# Does javascript regexp (|) pipe operator works same as the (||) logical operator?

Tags: javascript, regex, logical-operators

I know that the regexp OR (|) operator in javascript matches if one of the sub-strings on both sides of the regexp is matched.

I also know that in JavaScript the logical (||) OR operator checks the second operand only if the first operand is false.

So I want to know if the regexp (|) (also called pipe) OR operator works the same way or it first matches both the sub-strings and then decide the match.
If I am not wrong I think it should check the second right hand sub-string only when left hand sub-string is not matched for the sake of performance.

Comment: I'm sure it works in a similar fashion...it's called short-circuiting by the way. Is there any specific reason you want to know? Or is this just a general question?

Comment: @Ian: I was working with the javascript regexp and when I encountered the OR operator, I thought that with logical operators its very simple to implement the so called short-circuiting, but with regexp, I think there must be some performance or memory cost to implement the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `|` in regular expressions is short circuiting.

For example,

```
"The | is short circuiting, NOT!".match(/The \| is short circuiting(?:|, NOT!)/)
```

produces

```
["The | is short circuiting"]
```

while

```
"The | is not short circuiting, NOT!".match(/The \| is not short circuiting(?:, NOT!|)/)
```

produces

```
["The | is not short circuiting, NOT!"]
```

The [language specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.2.3) says

> The production *Disjunction* :: *Alternative* `|` *Disjunction* evaluates as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate Alternative to obtain a Matcher m1.
> 2. Evaluate Disjunction to obtain a Matcher m2.
> 3. Return an internal Matcher closure that takes two arguments, a State x and a Continuation c, and performs the following:
>
>    > a. Call m1(x, c) and let r be its result.
>    > b. **If r isn't failure, return r.**
>    > c. Call m2(x, c) and return its result.

15.10.2.3 line 3b is where the short-circuiting is specified.

Comment: Note however in step `2` that the Regex is *evaluated*, so it's not entirely short-circuiting.

Comment: @Kolink, no it's not.  Line 2 only serves to parse that structure to a matcher object.  Until that matcher is applied, no capturing groups are modified.  Moving line 2 after 3b would only lead to an observable effect if [chapter 16](http://es5.github.com/#x16) did not specify that regular expression parse errors are "early errors".  You can see that matcher 2 is not applied because if it were, then `"abc".match(/ab(?:|(c))/)` would have to return `["ab","c"]` but it instead returns `["ab",null]`.

Comment: That's right, but the reasoning is not quite bullet-proof. Strictly speaking, you can't tell if some crappy browser applies both matchers just to throw the second match away. I guess some performance test may give a hint on that.

Comment: In ES6, it should be [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-patterns), but please correct the link if wrong.

Comment: @community, you edited the post in 2020 but not to `es6`..